# Retrieving media (images, videos etc.) from links in Perl

Tags: python, perl, media, web-scraping, reddit

Similar to Reddit's r/pic sub-reddit, I want to aggregate media from various sources. Some sites use OEmbed specs to expose media on the page but not all sites do it. I was browsing through Reddit's source because essentially they 'scrape' links that users submit, retrieve images, videos etc. They create thumbnails which are then displayed along the link on their site. Now, I would like to do something similar and I looked at their code[1] and it seems that they have custom scrapers for each domain that they recognize and then they have a generic Scraper class that uses simple logic to get images from any domain (basically they retrieve the web-page, parse the html and then determine the largest image on the page which they then use to generate a thumbnail).

Since it's open source I can probably reuse the code for my application but unfortunately I have chosen Perl as this is a hobby project and I'm trying to learn Perl. Is there a Perl module which has similar functionality? If not, is there a Perl module that is similar to Python Imaging Library? It would be handy to determine the image sizes without actually downloading the whole image & thumbnail generation.

Thanks!

[1] https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/scraper.py

Answer (score 1):

[Image::Size](http://p3rl.org/Image%3a%3aSize) is the specialised module for determining image sizes from various format. It should be enough to read the first 1000 octets or so from a resource, enough for the diverse image headers, [into a buffer and operating on that](http://p3rl.org/Image%3a%3aSize#Input_Types). I have not tested this.

I do not know any general scraping module that has an API for HTTP range requests in order to avoid downloading the whole image resource, but it is easy to subclass [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I already know about WWW::Mechanize but I am mainly looking for retrieving the media on a page and package that already does that instead of writing my own.

Answer (score 0):

Try [PerlMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php), installation instruction is also listed there.